# is it possible to install the Microsoft "Azure IoT Suite" on premise in my vpn?

Tags: azure, vpn, iot

Azure IoT Suite [1] seems awesome, nevertheless I would like to use the IoT Suite on premises in my vpn.

Who can tell me whether Microsoft provides such local functionalities?

[1] http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/internet-of-things/azure-iot-suite.aspx

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place to speculate on future product plans and roadmap. Unfortunately, this question is off-topic.

Comment: @DavidMakogon its not asking for future, its asking for current, I would like to know the answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft is releasing [windows server 2016](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/?ocid=cloudplat_hp) allowing anyone to install the Windows Azure on premise.

Unfortunately Microsoft Azure IoT is not available for the moment on this Windows Server 2016 release